# How to share photos from Photos.app to Flickr retaining title, description and tags?

Tags: macos, photos.app, flickr

In the new Photos.app application, the export of photographs to other services is via the OS X extensibility feature. Sharing one picture to Flickr shows the picture's filename as the title and empty description and tags even though the pictures had these three fields filled in the 'Info' window. This metadata was exported fine with iPhoto which had its own sharing mechanism so this issue is either with Photos.app or with the extensibility feature of OS X. How can I upload pictures from Photos.app to Flickr without having to retype all the metadata for each one of them?

Comment: Any news on this? I just finished sharing 200 photos to discover all were missing keywords, titles, desciptions. (Geo locations were there, though)

Comment: No news & no good workaround either. Manual workaround is to display information, share picture by picture and manually copy the info from the Info box to the share box.

Answer (score 2):

Nearly a year later you would expect Flickr integration to have improved. As of February 2016 I have the exact same experience. To investigate further I opened this forum thread:

https://www.flickr.com/help/forum/en-us/72157665235195925/

Comment: That thread on Flickr suggested a working solution: to use the web uploader (accessed by clicking the cloud with arrow icon in the top right of the Flickr webpage). However note  that it doesn't work when dragging straight from Photo, one has to copy the pics to a directory and then drag them from the Finder to the web uploader.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted Apple about the inability of Photos to upload titles etc. After admitting there was a problem, the technician told me they would get back to me! No news since then.

Photos seems to be a very inferior software compared to iPhoto. I guess we will have to wait for an update with "improvements". The glitches and mistakes in the "improvement" may be even worse! Lol!

Answer (score -2):

have you tried Flickr Uploadr?
you can download it from here: https://www.flickr.com/tools/

I just tried... it automatize the uploading but as far I'm see did not export tags and titles.

Comment: As you point out it does not help.